# Deploying a new VM using Packstack and Ansible

Tags: ansible, virtual-machine, openstack

I have installed Packstack and Ansible 2.7.5 and I would like to make a test and deploy a VM using Ansible. I am using the following code:

```
--- #Deploy an instance
- name: Deploy an instance
  hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
  tasks: 
  - name: Deploy an instance
    os_server: 
       state: present
       auth: 
         auth_url: http://127.0.0.1:5000/v2.0/
         username: admin
         password: 712e207207aa4083 
         project_name: admin 
       name: webserver
       image: cirros
       key_name: root
       timeout: 200  
       flavor: 1
       nics:
        - net-id: fa6af4e6-c44e-439c-a91c-03bcae55e587
       meta:
        hostname: webserver.localdomain
```

When I am running it, I am getting the following error:

```
TASK [Deploy an instance] *****************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "To utilize this module, the installed version ofthe openstacksdk library MUST be >=0.12.0"}
    to retry, use: --limit @/home/dante/Openstack/deployment.retry

PLAY RECAP ********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=0    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=1
```

I have tried to install also the Openstacksdk 0.12.0, but I am getting some other errors related to dependencies:

```
[dante@localhost Openstack]$ sudo pip install openstacksdk==0.12.0
...
Installing collected packages: ipaddress, os-service-types, PyYAML, openstacksdk
  Found existing installation: ipaddress 1.0.16
Cannot uninstall 'ipaddress'. It is a distutils installed project and thus we cannot accurately determine which files belong to it which would lead to only a partial uninstall.
```

Is any way to correct this? Or, if this module is to new and has too many bugs, is any other way to create a VM in Openstack using Ansible? I have checked also the version of nova_compute module, but it says that this Ansible module is deprecated after Ansible 2.0.

Best regards,
Romain

Comment: Where did you get Ansible 2.7.5 from?

Comment: @techraf: I am using some EC2 servers and this was the last version of Ansible available for that repo.

Comment: Interesting, because the most recent version as of today is 2.6.2.

Comment: Probably he meant Python 2.7.5?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was solved by installing the openstacksdk with all its dependencies in the end. Here is also the code:

```
--- #Deploy an instance
- name: Deploy an instance
  hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
  tasks: 
  - name: Deploy an instance
    os_server: 
       state: present
       auth: 
         auth_url: http://<URL TAKEN FROM SOURCE FILE> 
         username: <USERNAME>
         password: <PASSWORD> 
       name: webserver
       image: <ID OF THE IMAGE>
       timeout: 700  
       flavor: 1
       auto_floating_ip: yes
    register: webserver
```

Answer (score 0):

although in your hosts: is localhost, you still need to tell it the connection type https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_delegation.html so you can use delegate_to: localhost or connection: localhost . This is required for any modules that talk to an API or doesn't require an ssh connection to do the tasks. For example, aws, gitlab, github, nios modules.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but in the end, it was solved by installing that packet with all its required dependencies.

Comment: I missed that part. You are using a very old version of ansible. you should try a newer version since its easier to do this.

Comment: I think that the last version of Ansible is this one: 2.7.5

Comment: 2.7.5 is in dev and not officially released. 2.6.2 is the latest.